# How to lookup tables initialized with estimators?

Tags: tensorflow, tensor

I train a linear model with tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate and save model by `tf.estimator.RunConfig(model_dir=FLAGS.checkpoints_dir,save_checkpoints_steps=FLAGS.save_checkpoints_steps)`. Now I want to inference with the saved model, meet the error "Table not initialized", how should solve this problem?